# Different alt-text per node for media entity image

Tags: media, 10

Is there a known solution for beeing able to change the alt text of an image (From the media module) on a node level.

So I have one image in my image library. I have two nodes.

- Node 1: About me, where I added the image from the library and I want
  to have an alt text: "Portret of me".
- Node 2: Homepage, where I added
  the samen image from the library and I want to have an alt text: "Employee
  of the month, me".

I need this because I do want to use the media library but I also want my site to be accessible. So the alt can't be the same on all pages.

Comment: Are these image fields or WYSIWYGs (or both?)

Comment: It seems like a great case for Paragraphs, or Entity reference where you add a new text field to it to use as the alt, and then adjusting the HTML output to use that text as the alt instead of using the Media alt.

Comment: I mainly use this with image fields. And extra field is a good option for one image, but using a multi item field makes it complex.